# Visual Studio Code(node.js) Отладчик недоступен, не удается отправить "variables"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Решал задачу в которой требовалось создать древовидный map объект
Дерево имеет такой вид:

```
Map(1){
  1 => Map(1){
    2 => Map(1){...}
  }
}
```

При выводе его через console.log получаю это: [image: скриншот из vscode]
На stackoverflow нашел вроде решение, прописать **"outputCapture": "std"**, в launch.json, но он выводит только 3 уровня вложенности и то в строку:
[image: скриншот из vscode c решением со stackoverflow]
Есть ли какое нибудь решение этой проблемы? Заранее благдарю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, вы имели ввиду вывод с использованием [console.dir](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoledirobj-options):

```js
// @ts-check

/**
 * @typedef {Map<number, TMap>} TMap
 */

/** @type {TMap} */
const root = new Map();
{
  /** @type {TMap} */
  let current = root;
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    current.set(i, current = new Map());
  }
}

console.dir(root, {
  depth: null,
  maxArrayLength: null,
  maxStringLength: null,
  compact: false,
  getters: true,
});
```

Что будет напечатанно в консоли после запуска:

```bash
$ node inspect.js 
Map(1) {
  1 => Map(1) {
    2 => Map(1) {
      3 => Map(1) {
        4 => Map(1) {
          5 => Map(1) {
            6 => Map(1) {
              7 => Map(1) {
                8 => Map(1) {
                  9 => Map(0) {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо